# Parse Error (x + 1) when Compiling in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, compilation

I'm doing this assignment and I'm desperate to get this to work. 
I know that this isn't the smartest way, and that it is not the most efficient way. I did this purely because I want to test how inefficient this code is.

```
transition_from_conductor :: Element_w_Coord Cell -> List_2D Cell -> Cell
transition_from_conductor element world = case num_of_heads_around_conductor (0, element) world of
    1 -> Head
    2 -> Head
    _ -> Conductor
    where
        num_of_heads_around_conductor :: (Int, Element_w_Coord Cell) -> List_2D Cell -> Int
        num_of_heads_around_conductor (i, (cell, (x, y))) ((w_cell, (w_x, w_y): rest)) = case rest of
            [] -> i
            _  -> case (w_cell, w_x, w_y) of
                (Head, (x + 1),  y)        -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
                (Head, (x + 1), (y + 1))   -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
                (Head, (x + 1), (y - 1))   -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
                (Head, (x - 1),  y)        -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
                (Head, (x - 1), (y + 1))   -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
                (Head, (x - 1), (y - 1))   -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
                (Head,  x,      (y + 1))   -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
                (Head,  x,      (y - 1))   -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
                _                          -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ( i     , (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
```

If I try to run this in terminal, it gives me parse error (x + 1) on the

```
(Head, (x + 1), y) .....
```

What did I do wrong? and how do I fix it?

A few things...

```
type List_2D e = [Element_w_Coord e]
type Element_w_Coord e = (e, Coord)
type Coord = (X_Coord, Y_Coord)
type X_Coord = Integer
type Y_Coord = Integer
```

Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things wrong here:

- you can't use an arithmetic expression in a pattern
- when you try to pattern match against `x` and `y` you intend to constrain those parts of the pattern to be equal to the existing `x` and `y` variables, but you instead create new variables `x` and `y`

I would use guards.

```
_  -> case (w_cell, w_x, w_y) of
    (Head, x', y')
        | x' == x + 1 && y' == y     -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
        | x' == x + 1 && y' == y + 1 -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
        | x' == x + 1 && y' == y - 1 -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
        | x' == x - 1 && y' == y     -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
        | x' == x - 1 && y' == y + 1 -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
        | x' == x - 1 && y' == y - 1 -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
        | x' == x     && y' == y + 1 -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
        | x' == x     && y' == y - 1 -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
    _                                -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ( i     , (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
```

And then simplify:

```
_  -> case (w_cell, w_x, w_y) of
    (Head, x', y')
        |    x' == x + 1 && (y' == y || y' == y + 1 || y' == y - 1)
          || x' == x - 1 && (y' == y || y' == y + 1 || y' == y - 1)
          || x' == x     &&            (y' == y + 1 || y' == y - 1)
        -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ((i + 1), (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
    _   -> num_of_heads_around_conductor ( i     , (cell, (x, y))) (rest)
```

No doubt this can be simplified further.

Comment: Do we know that `abs (x - x') < 2 && abs (y - y') < 2`? I haven't read the OP's code closely enough to tell.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to match the surrounding 8 neighbours of a cell in a grid, so that, plus an exception for an exact match, should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

What you have used is an "n + k" pattern, which has been removed from the language.  You can no longer pattern match on integers using '+'.  For the most part, pattern matches are restricted to constructors and literals.

To achieve the same result as your pattern match, I suggest:

```
(Head, x0,  y)        -> let x = x0 - 1 in ...
```

Notice that there is also more wrong with this code - the pattern matches are overlapped.  For example: Even with n+k support, there is no case in which the pattern:

```
(Head, (x + 1),  y)
```

Fails and the next pattern of:

```
(Head, (x + 1), (y + 1))
```

succeeds.  In other words, you have many cases that can never be executed.

Comment: Could use view patterns: (Head,subtract 1 -> x,y)

Comment: It seems like the intention was to match against the values of `x` and `y` from the outer scope, not a n+k pattern. See dave4420's answer.